# Scons: overriding SConscript() function to get a list all loaded SConscripts

Tags: python, scons

I am trying to get a list of included python Scons files (which are included via env.SConscript) function for some dependency analyzis. Scons version is 4.4.0

So after a building of a script d.py containing

```
env.SConscript('#a.py', exports='env')
env.SConscript('#b.py', exports='env')
```

I would like to have a list ['a.py', 'b.py']

1. I was not able to the list of included ".py" files from the --tree dependency view of Scons
2. Another idea was to override the SConscript function (SCons.Environment) to make an own list:

```
def deco(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kw):
            print("name goes here")
            func(*args, **kw)
        return wrapped
Environment.SConscript = deco(Environment.SConscript)
```

This approach fails with

```
scons: *** Export of non-existent variable ''env''
```

Same happens when makeing a fake Envionment class.

Any ideas how to solve this?

upd 2023-06-22:

running with scons --debug=stacktrace gives

```
Running with -j 15
name goes here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <path>\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 97, in compute_exports
    retval[export] = loc[export]
                     ~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'env'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 99, in compute_exports
    retval[export] = glob[export]
                     ~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'env'
```

Comment: Please rerun with `scons --debug=stacktrace` and paste the stacktrace into your question so we can see better what's happening

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to make out what you're asking for.  Build scripts are *not* part of the dependency graph, they are files containing instructions for building the dependency graph. So you don't see those in the tree output.

Comment: @bdbaddog see update above, please

Comment: @MatsWichmann i would like to see a list of all included build scripts.

Comment: Do you set up your `deco` before you create the `env=Environment(...)` ?

Comment: Any chance you can create a toy example repo on github and share that? (very small reproducer is what would be helpful)

Comment: @bdbaddog i have tried before and after, but same error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def deco(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kw):
            print("name goes here")
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return wrapped
env.SConscript = deco(env.SConscript)
```

Calls to SConscript are expected to return a value.

Comment: same: scons: *** Export of non-existent variable ''env''

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to capture accurately in a simple way because of the number of options. An `SConscript` call may be made using the global func or the environment method (you have the latter).  The call may include a script name or script name list, or it may include a directory name or directory name list passed as a keyword argument, in which case the same script name is looked for in each directory. That name can optionally be specified (if different from "SConscript") using another keyword argument. Then, the physical location of each script can be in the specific directory you asked for, or it can be in a different directory (source dir if variant dirs in effect, or repository). Which one would you want printed?

All that said I think you can make some progress, if all you want is a debug-style printout of calls, by decorating one layer down the stack, around `SCons.Script.SConscript._SConscript`, which has a different signature. This example minimally works for me - without accounting for any of the permutations I mention (i.e., the path/scriptname may not actually be in the `files` arguments):

```py
def deco(func):                                                                
    def wrapped(fs, *files, **kw):                                             
        for file in files:                                                     
            print(f"SConscript called: {file}")                                
        return func(fs, *files, **kw)                                          
                                                                               
    return wrapped
```

Comment: i think we are coming closer, unfortunately i cannot override the inner function. Coudld you show your code please. I use ```from SCons import Script```  and ```Script.SConscript._SConscript = deco(Script.SConscript._SConscript)```  it gives me ``` AttributeError: 'DefaultEnvironmentCall' object has no attribute '_SConscript': ```

Comment: Sorry, I just added the decorator in the SCons code itself to quickly test (`@deco` on `_SConscript`).  It may not work to do from "outside" due to needed context... will try to get a chance to think about that.

Comment: @Mate Wichmann: i wanted to avoid patching Scons Code

Comment: I get that, but I'm not seeing any good way around it at the moment. SCons has some "clever tricks" to make sure there's an initial environment and that doesn't work for the `_SConscript` function. And trying to grab the actual `SConscript` function has its own problems as you've already seen.

Comment: If the implementation was reasonable, we could definitely merge it into SCons. Others could find it useful.

Comment: If you want to drop by the SCons project and describe the requirement, we can make up an enhancement request.  It's technically easy add a debug option to print out the sconscript names as they're being executed, but not going to dive in on that if it doesn't actually fill the need. You can find links at scons.org.

Comment: A followup note - just remembered that if you add `--debug=time` the time-spent output adds a line for each SConscript executed.

Comment: We ended up adding two print statements around "exec(copmile(..." line within SConscript.py

 ```                             print("scons-entering>"+str(scriptname))
                            exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
                            print("scons-exiting>"+str(scriptname))
```
 @bdbaddog is this the way to go?

Comment: @Stasik - Submit a PR and we'll help you work through what's needed.. https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/GitWorkflows

Comment: I did prototype something, wasn't happy with the begin/end display so ended up just printing at startup, and using a computed indent to help show the nesting. We can work through that over in the repository if you want to pursue.